# Do we want hats? Voulons-nous des chapeaux ?

Tags: discussion, design

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the holiday theme to any site that wants to participate.

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Hats will be shown to visitors by default, but logged-in users can click an "I hate hats" button to see the normal hatless avatars.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by **28 November 2012** (i.e. in barely two days), so please tell us really soon if you want or do not want hats. Moderators will make the final decision, but we'll take your feedback into account.

<sub>*Apologies for the late posting, I initially mistakenly thought this didn't apply to beta sites.*</sub>

---

En 2011, le site [Jeux Vidéos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) s'est [revêtu de chapeaux pour les fêtes](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/). Les utilisateurs pouvaient gagner des chapeaux pour leurs avatars en accomplissant des tâches similaires à celles qui permettent de gagner des [badges](https://french.stackexchange.com/badges) :

[image]

Cette année, chaque site peut choisir de participer ou non à l'évènement. Les chapeaux sont les mêmes pour tous, nous n'aurons pas de bérêt. Sur les sites partipants :

- Du 19 décembre 2012 au 5 janvier 2013, les avatars seront ainsi décorés.
- Les utilisateurs pourront voir leur collection de chapeaux sur http://winterba.sh. Ce site disposera d'une page d'accueil expliquant les règles de l'évènement.
- Tous les visiteurs verront les avatars avec chapeaux. Les utilisateurs identifiés disposeront d'un bouton « *I hate hats* » (« je hais les chapeaux ») qui leur permettront de voir les avatars sous leur aspect habituel.
- Les seuls changements apportés au site seront l'apparence des avatars et le bouton supplémentaire « *I hate hats* ».

Nous devons répondre avant le **28 novembre** pour dire si nous souhaitons participer. Les modérateurs prendront la décision finale, mais nous tiendrons compte de votre avis si vous l'exprimez ici.

Comment: Les chapeaux sont là :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Totalement inutile, donc rigoureusement indispensable :D

Comment: J'aime cette réponse! :D

Answer (score 3):

Based on the positive response, we have opted in.

---

Au vu de la réaction positive, nous avons choisi de participer.

Answer (score 2):

C'est une très bonne initiative. Chapeau !

Quelqu'un nous fera-t-il goûter la [Soup (sic) du jour](http://winterba.sh/soup-du-jour) ?

---

It's a very good initiative… hum… Hat!

Anyone care to share a [Soup (sic) du jour](http://winterba.sh/soup-du-jour) with us?