# Winter Bash, édition 2013

Tags: discussion, design

Comme [l'an dernier](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/385/82), Winter Bash approche, et les site du réseau Stack Exchange désireux d'accroître leur charisme du 13 décembre 2013 au 3 janvier 2014 au moyen de chapeaux fort seyants sont priés de se faire connaître. Y participerons-nous cette année encore ?

Les réponses des modérateurs sont attendues par les sorciers noirs de Stack Exchange avant le premier décembre, que ceux qui le souhaitent s'expriment donc avant le 30 novembre ou se taisent à jamais.

Pour plus de détails sur Winter Bash, voici un honteux copié-collé du post d'explications de l'an dernier

---

Brace yourselves! As it did [last year](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/385/82), Winter Bash is coming. From 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014, the Stack Exchange network sites are once again enhancing their already overwhelming charisma with the cunning use of really slick hats. Will we join their mighty effort?

We, the local mods, are expected to give your answer our evil overlords of Stack Exchange before 1 December, so, good citizens, if you want to make your decision known, write hereunder before the 30th of November, or remain silent forever.

For more details on Winter Bash, Lo! I bring you, from the limbos of Meta, Gilles' explanation from last year.

---

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the holiday theme to any site that wants to participate.

- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Hats will be shown to visitors by default, but logged-in users can click an "I hate hats" button to see the normal hatless avatars.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

---

En 2011, le site [Jeux Vidéos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) s'est [revêtu de chapeaux pour les fêtes](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/). Les utilisateurs pouvaient gagner des chapeaux pour leurs avatars en accomplissant des tâches similaires à celles qui permettent de gagner des [badges](https://french.stackexchange.com/badges) :

[image]

Cette année, chaque site peut choisir de participer ou non à l'évènement. Les chapeaux sont les mêmes pour tous, nous n'aurons pas de bérêt. Sur les sites partipants :

- Les utilisateurs pourront voir leur collection de chapeaux sur http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. Ce site disposera d'une page d'accueil expliquant les règles de l'évènement.
- Tous les visiteurs verront les avatars avec chapeaux. Les utilisateurs identifiés disposeront d'un bouton « *I hate hats* » (« je hais les chapeaux ») qui leur permettront de voir les avatars sous leur aspect habituel.
- Les seuls changements apportés au site seront l'apparence des avatars et le bouton supplémentaire « *I hate hats* ».

Answer (score 5):

J'ai envoyé un courriel pour dire que nous participons.

---

I sent an email saying we're opting in.