# Une compétition d'écriture sur méta ? — A writing competition on meta?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred

Sur le site méta principal de Stack Exchange, il y a eu récemment une [compétition d'écriture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212433/should-employees-with-head-injuries-be-allowed-to-post-on-meta) dont le principe était de raconter une histoire incluant deux noms de [chapeaux](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/winter-bash-edition-2013) avec quelques contraintes sur le thème.

Et si nous organisions quelque chose du même type, en français bien sûr ? Il y aurait probablement un prix à la clé (du genre T-shirt Stack Exchange, peut-être même une tasse), mais attention, je ne promets rien, cela reste à confirmer.

Il faudrait avoir un nombre non ridicule de participants (il y a eu 51 réponses sur le site méta principal, bien sûr on n'en espère pas autant ici, mais il faudrait éviter d'avoir un gagnant avant-dernier et un dernier en deuxième place…). Alors, on tente ?

À priori cela durerait quelques jours entre Noël et le jour de l'an. Si on le fait, les modérateurs se concerteront pour donner les règles précises (probablement proches de celles de la compétition originale).

---

Summary: should we organize a hat-themed writing contest like [Tim Post's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212433/should-employees-with-head-injuries-be-allowed-to-post-on-meta)? There *may* be a prize, but no guarantees. Would we achieve non-ridiculous participation?

Comment: Voir message de @Gilles dans  Cosette. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12789916#12789916   **si il y a 3 vues d'ici le 26 on fait pas, s'il y a 10 upvotes on fait, entre les deux on verra**